# Nested push in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, query, update

I have a user schema like that:

```
name: String,
nick: String,
email: String,
password: String,

bio: String,
color: String,
followers: [String],
followings: [String],

posts: [{
    author: {
        name: String,
        nick: String
    },
    content: String,
    date: Date,
    simpleDate: String,
    color: String,
    likes: [String]
}]
```

I want to when user push the like button my backend take the id of post and add user's nick to array that named "likes". So I want to find the object that has post that has this id and add a new string to likes array of it.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({'posts._id': req.params.postId},{$push:{posts:{likes:{likes:req.header.authenticatedUser.nick}}}},
    (err,result) => {...});
```

I tried something like that but it's not working and looks like very wrong.

How can I find and push to nested object like that?

-edit-

When I use the code below

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({'posts._id': req.params.postId},{"$push":{"posts":{"likes":req.header.authenticatedUser.nick}}},(err,results)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

it adds a likes array to posts. But I want add my usurname to likes array of post that has index 2
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error which you got?

Comment: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ likes: { likes: 'zuck' } }" at path "posts"
My way is totally wrong. I can't find the even correct post.

Answer (score 1):

Before the change your application code, you should try to mongo shell this command on your test environment.

```
db.test.findOneAndUpdate({},
    {"$push":
        {"post.2.likes":"Yunus"}
    })
```

[image]

Comment: I add a photo to my question, can you look at that?

Comment: Yes, I changed my answer. Hope I understood your question.

Comment: There is one more thing: The program must determine the index of the post that has req.params.postId.

Comment: Oh, I see. First of all, you have to get an index number and set it to a variable. After that, you can use this like the above.

Comment: Is there any way to get both them via one query? Or how I can use that variable in the that string "post.2.likes" ? The first idea is var q = "post."+indexNumber+".likes" but it's ugly.

Comment: That is all I know. You should probably, fire a new question on your app language stack for this.